# How to set number of nodes in omnet, veins and sumo simulation?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am simulating a flooding protocol using omnet++, veins and sumo. I want to repeat the simulation with different number of nodes (say 50, 100 and 150). Is there a way to specify that how many (maximum) nodes are created in a particular simulation?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Veins, you can set the number of vehicles in the `omnetpp.ini` file. If you have a look to the configuration of the Erlangen scenario, you can find the parameters for the `TraCIScenarioManager`. By using that instance, you can specify the number of vehicles in your simulation by setting the `numVehicles` attribute. The result could look like this:

```
*.manager.updateInterval = 1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("erlangen.launchd.xml")
*.manager.configFile = "erlangen.sumo.cfg"
*.manager.numVehicles = 150
```

With OMNeT++ you can do parameter studies, which are multiple simulation runs with different parameter values. The [OMNeT++ TicToc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/) shows you how to do that.

The `numVehicles` attribute only sets the amount of vehicles inserted by Veins. If you specify additional vehicles in your SUMO configuration, they will be added as well.